# Is there a way to get the edges to be a similar distance appart?

Tags: modeling

I wanted to make the center of this circle be in the center of all the edges of this sphere. I don't want to use ctrl g because that may lead to human error.[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use vertex snapping for perfect precision.

1. Enable *Vertex Snapping > Center*
2. Select your center vertex and align it (using snapping) if it's not already
3. Select your ring and snap it to the aligned center vertex.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using the snap to function it's quite easy.

In *Edit Mode* select the edge you want to align to, then press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> and select *Cursor to Selected*. The 3D Cursor will be placed in the middle of your selected edge.